# Please review my test architecture (in memory database)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I've just started with unit testing, and would like to know if I'm on the right track. Can you guys please take a look at my code and tell me what you think if it?

This is the (basic) method that I want to test:

```
public void Accept(long resumeId)
{
   // Get the resume that has to be accepted
   Resume originalResume = ResumeDAC.GetById(id);

   // Make a copy of the resume
   Resume resumeCopy = CopyResume(originalResume );

   // Accept the original resume and lock it
   originalResume .AcceptAndLock();

   // Accept the copy and keep it open for editing
   resumeCopy.AcceptAndKeepOpen();

   // Add the copy to the database
   ResumeDAC.Add(resumeCopy);

   // Commit everything
   ResumeDAC.Commit();
}
```

What I want to test is this:

- The original resume has the status 'AcceptedAndLocked'
- The copied resume has the status 'AcceptedAndOpen'
- The copied resume was added to the database

I don't want to use the actual database in this test, but I have two classes that use the database: EmployeeDAC and ResumeDAC.
EmployeeDac is easy, so I've mocked it with Rhino Mocks.
ResumeDAC is a bit harder I think because a 'resume copy' is made and added to the database. I want to assert that the resume copy is added to the database.

Let's take a look at my testcode:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAcceptResume()
{
   // Arrange
   // These two classes are used for database actions
   EmployeeDAC mockEmployeeDAC = ArrangeEmployeeDAC(); // Simply mocked with Rhino Mocks
   TestResumeDAC mockResumeDac = new TestResumeDAC(); //I've created my own test double. See below

   // Inject the two Data Access Classes into the ResumeService
   var resumeService = new ResumeService("", mockResumeDac, mockEmployeeDAC);

   // Act
   var resume = resumeService.Accept(3);

   // Assert
   Resume origResume = mockResumeDac.Resumes.Single(it => it.Id == resumeId);
   Assert.AreEqual("AcceptedAndLocked", origResume.StatusName);
   Assert.AreEqual(4, mockResumeDac.Resumes.Count); // Expect 4 records in the database
}
```

The is my own testversion of the ResumeDAC (Data Access Class) used in the test

```
internal class TestResumeDAC : ResumeDAC
{
   public TestResumeDAC() : base()
   {
      Resumes = new List<Resume>();

      // Add resumes to the list
      AddResumes();
   }

   public List<Resume> Resumes { get; set; }

   public override void Add(Resume resume)
   {
      Resumes.Add(resume);
   }

   public override void Commit()
   {
   }

   public override Resume GetById(long id)
   {
      return Resumes.SingleOrDefault(it => it.Id == id);
   }
}
```

As you can see I've made kind of a in memory database. This makes is easy for me to see if objects are added or deleted etc.

So my question is: how do you like this code? Please let me know if this is not the way to go, or any erros I've made in my thinking, tips etc.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. Stackoverflow is not rentacoder.com ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this code isn't working for you.  Is it?  You didn't say...

Anyhow, I took a long look at unit testing at the behest of one of my managers.  I ended up using "The Art of Unit Testing", by Roy Osherove.  It's a very good introduction to unit testing.

It looks like you might have made `ResumeDAC` is a static class.  In order to override it with your test class `ResumeDAC`, you'll have to get rid of the static method calls.

In any case, the issue at hand is probably replacing `ResumeDAC` with your test version of the class.  This is called "dependency injection".